# What is "Developer Program Member" on Github.com

Tags: github, github-api

I have seen couple of Github profiles having "Developer Program Member". I searched on Google a lot but not able to find how people get that in their profile.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is for developers registered to the [**GitHub Developer Program**](https://developer.github.com/program/) (like this [GitHub profile](https://github.com/xPaw), for instance)

> Membership is open to individual developers and companies who have:
>
> - A <del>paid</del> GitHub.com personal or organization plan
>     (since 2019, you don't need a paid membership anymore)
> - An integration in production or development using the GitHub API
> - An email address where GitHub users can contact you for support

That allows for:

> #### Staying in the know:
>
> Be the first to know about API changes and try out new features before they launch.
>
> #### Scratching an itch
>
> Build your own tools that seamlessly integrate with the place you push code every day.
>
> #### Taking on the enterprise
>
> Obtain developer licenses to build and test your application against GitHub Enterprise.

Answer (score 22):

By joining this Developer Program,

1) You'll receive ongoing notifications about changes to Github API.

2) You can request a development license for GitHub Enterprise.

3) You can also submit your work for consideration on the integrations page.

**Go to this link:**
https://developer.github.com/program/